# What is the benefit of parentheses in that case?

Tags: c++

I have a simple thing ambiguous for me.

```
Tea* mintTea = new Builder()->cup(2)->sugar(3)->flavour("mint")->build();
```

The previous code gives me an error: `C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'Builder * to 'Tea *`.

But when putting parentheses around `new Builder()` the code works well.

```
Tea* mintTea = (new Builder())->cup(2)->sugar(3)->flavour("mint")->build();
```

Full Code:

```
class Tea;
class Builder {
public:
    Builder() = default;
    ~Builder() = default;
    int m_suger;
    int m_cup;
    string m_flavour;

    Builder* sugar(int sugar);
    Builder* cup(int cup);
    Builder* flavour(string flavour);
    Tea* build();
};
Builder * Builder::sugar(int sugar) {
    this->m_suger = sugar;
    return this;
}
Builder * Builder::cup(int cup) {
    this->m_cup = cup;
    return this;
}
Builder * Builder::flavour(string flavour) {
    this->m_flavour = flavour;
    return this;
}
Tea * Builder::build() {
    return new Tea(this);
}


class Builder;
class Tea {
public: 
    int m_suger;
    int m_cup;
    string m_flavour;

    Tea() = default;
    Tea(Builder* b);
    ~Tea() = default;
};

Tea::Tea(Builder * b) {
    m_suger = b->m_suger;
    m_cup = b->m_cup;
    m_flavour = b->m_flavour;
    cout << "Hot " << b->m_cup << " cup of tea is comming!, with " << b->m_flavour << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Tea* mintTea = (new Builder())->cup(2)->sugar(3)->flavour("mint")->build();
    return 0;
}
```

**What is the benefit of parentheses in that case?**

Comment: I'd just like to point out that it seems that new-ing the Builder is not only completely unnecessary but also prevents leaking it.

Comment: There are to many `new`s.

Comment: Hint: smart pointers. Don't write C++98 in 2018.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Do you mean `return this` returns a new dynamic instance each time?

Comment: No, I mean that you should not be allocating `Builder` via `new` as you will have a memory leak - what is getting stored in the pointer is the result of the `new`  in the `build()` function

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Sorry, but your notice still didn't reach my brain. What's the problem of `new` with `Builder`?

Comment: You can never delete the pointer that returns, so you have a  leak.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: `Build()` method returns a `Tea` pointer, so `Tea* mintTea` will receive the pointer of `Tea`, and when I want to delete the pointer `delete mintTea`. so, where the memory leak that you meant?

Comment: The leak is when you say `(new Builder())` - that pointer is discarded at the end of the statement.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: ah, now I understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The member access by pointer operator `->` has precedence over the operator `new` (not to be confused with `operator new()`). So, somewhat confusingly, the value of the expression:

```
new Builder()->cup(2)->sugar(3)->flavour("mint")->build()
```

-- is actually `Builder*` and not `Tea*`. That is why you need the parentheses, so `new` is executed first and then your property functions can be called and a `Tea*` returned.

With the parentheses fix, this leaks memory: there is no way to recover the `Builder*` value returned by `new` and thus no way to `delete` it. Every time you build a `Tea` object you leak 2 integers and a string.

The fix for both of these problems is in the operator precedence table: notice that function calls are the same precedence as member access and have left-to-right associativity. So, instead use a static function, make sure Builder is trivially copy constructible, and return by value:

```
class Builder {
    public:
        Builder() : m_sugar(0), m_cup(1), m_flavour("earl grey, hot") {}
        static Builder get() { return Builder(); }
        Builder sugar(int sugar) { m_sugar = sugar; return *this; }
        Builder cup(int cup) { m_cup = cup; return *this; }
        Builder flavour(string flavour) { m_flavour = flavour; return *this; }
        Tea* pour() { Tea* hotCuppa = new Tea(this); return hotCuppa; }
    private:
        int m_sugar;
        int m_cup;
        string m_flavour;
};
```

Now you can write:

```
Tea* tea42 = Builder::get().cup(2).sugar(3).flavour("mint").pour();
```

Though unless you *really need* pointers to `Tea` objects, I wouldn't use the factory pattern to build pointers: it get's confusing as to who owns the pointer.

Edit: @songyuanyao answered this much better and more accurately than I did.

Answer (score 3):

Without the parentheses, `new Builder()->cup(2)->sugar(3)->flavour("mint")->build();` doesn't match the correct syntax of [new expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new):

> ```
> ::(optional) new (placement_params)(optional) ( type ) initializer(optional)  (1) 
> ::(optional) new (placement_params)(optional) type initializer(optional)      (2)
> ```

The compiler will complain about it, because `new Builder()->cup(2)->sugar(3)->flavour("mint")->build()` can't be interpreted as a valid new expression. Such as [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DNInIHf5QsF96NiK):

```
prog.cc:56:33: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    Tea* mintTea = new Builder()->cup(2)->sugar(3)->flavour("mint")->build();
                                ^
                                ;
```

Then the compiler suppose the new expression ends after `new Builder()`, then gives the error message said:

```
prog.cc:56:10: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'Tea *' with an rvalue of type 'Builder *'
    Tea* mintTea = new Builder()->cup(2)->sugar(3)->flavour("mint")->build();
         ^         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

You compiler's error message (i.e. `C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'Builder * to 'Tea *`) says the same thing.

With the parentheses it works fine because the range of new expression is limited in the parentheses:

```
  (new Builder())->cup(2)->sugar(3)->flavour("mint")->build();
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~  the new expression; which returns a Builder*, and all the following code would work fine
```